# How to change the Event object Description Field type to Rich Text?

Tags: standard-objects, event, data-types

As the question says, I would like to change the data type of the Description field on Event Object?

Currently it is Text Area but we would like to change it as `Rich Text Are` as we have some html tags in that field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of the box (OotB) fields can't have their data type changed. Also, Events do not support custom Long Text fields (including RTA), so there's no convenient way to include this data on the Event record using just OotB configuration. You'd have to sort to some sort of trickery using Visualforce and attachments/documents/something else to make it happen.

Comment: I don't know this with any certainty, but I suspect using anything other than Long Text could possibly impact display of events on the SF calendar. This could potentially lead to major problems if a RTA was injected into a calendar field.